# Problemas con Django: Asignacion de autor en Post da error

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

No consigo que mi aplicacion asigne como autor a un post, en base al usuario que ha iniciado la sesion en la administracion de Django. En otras palabras quiero que el campo 'autor' no sea editable y venga por defecto segun sea el usuario que lo esté publicando.

admin.py la clase que da el error:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=("titulo", "autor", "created", "updated")
    search_fields=("titulo",)
    readonly_fields = ('created','updated')
    list_filter= ("created",)
    date_hierarchy="created"
    
        def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):#Aquí ocurre el problema
            if not obj.autor: #Si el objeto no recibe la id del autor
                obj.autor == request.User.id
            obj.save()
    
    admin.site.register(Categoria, CategoriaAdmin)
    admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Aqui está el codigo del modelo:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contenido = RichTextField(max_length=3000)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to="AppBlog", null=False, blank=False, default=None) 
    autor = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categorias = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)#auto_now_add permite guardar la fecha instantaneamente
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name= "Post" 
        verbose_name_plural= "Posts"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

Answer (score 0):

Considero que el error esta aqui:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):  # Aquí ocurre el problema
    if not obj.autor:  # Si el objeto no recibe la id del autor
        obj.autor = request.user
    obj.save()
```

Estas usando '==' en lugar de '=' para asignar el usuario. Y solo es necesario asignar request.user

Saludos y no olvides incluir el mensaje de error en tus preguntas y siempre ser lo mas descriptivo posible.